# How to sort a large array according to the alphabet specified in the array with a minimum loss of time?

Tags: php, arrays, performance, sorting

How I can sort array with million values by letters specified in the array effectively with minimal waste of time.

```
$letters = array(
"а","б", "в", "г", "ғ", "д", "е", "ё", "ҷ", "ж", "з", "и", "ӣ", "й", "к", "қ", "л", "м", "н", "о", "п", "р", "с", "т", "у", "ӯ", "ф", "х", "ҳ", "ч", "ш", "ъ", "э", "ю", "я"
);
```

Simple function to sort an array by a specific key. Maintains index association. This function also sorts the array, but not in my alphabet, but in English alphabet (works better in English letters).

```
<?php

function array_sort($array, $on, $order=SORT_ASC)
{
    $new_array = array();
    $sortable_array = array();

    if (count($array) > 0) {
        foreach ($array as $k => $v) {
            if (is_array($v)) {
                foreach ($v as $k2 => $v2) {
                    if ($k2 == $on) {
                        $sortable_array[$k] = $v2;
                    }
                }
            } else {
                $sortable_array[$k] = $v;
            }
        }

        switch ($order) {
            case SORT_ASC:
                asort($sortable_array);
            break;
            case SORT_DESC:
                arsort($sortable_array);
            break;
        }

        foreach ($sortable_array as $k => $v) {
            $new_array[$k] = $array[$k];
        }
    }

    return $new_array;
}

$people = array(
    12345 => array(
        'id' => 12345,
        'first_name' => 'Joe',
        'surname' => 'Bloggs',
        'age' => 23,
        'sex' => 'm'
    ),
    12346 => array(
        'id' => 12346,
        'first_name' => 'Adam',
        'surname' => 'Smith',
        'age' => 18,
        'sex' => 'm'
    ),
    12347 => array(
        'id' => 12347,
        'first_name' => 'Amy',
        'surname' => 'Jones',
        'age' => 21,
        'sex' => 'f'
    )
);

print_r(array_sort($people, 'age', SORT_DESC)); // Sort by oldest first
print_r(array_sort($people, 'surname', SORT_ASC)); // Sort by surname

/*
Array
(
    [12345] => Array
        (
            [id] => 12345
            [first_name] => Joe
            [surname] => Bloggs
            [age] => 23
            [sex] => m
        )

    [12347] => Array
        (
            [id] => 12347
            [first_name] => Amy
            [surname] => Jones
            [age] => 21
            [sex] => f
        )

    [12346] => Array
        (
            [id] => 12346
            [first_name] => Adam
            [surname] => Smith
            [age] => 18
            [sex] => m
        )

)
Array
(
    [12345] => Array
        (
            [id] => 12345
            [first_name] => Joe
            [surname] => Bloggs
            [age] => 23
            [sex] => m
        )

    [12347] => Array
        (
            [id] => 12347
            [first_name] => Amy
            [surname] => Jones
            [age] => 21
            [sex] => f
        )

    [12346] => Array
        (
            [id] => 12346
            [first_name] => Adam
            [surname] => Smith
            [age] => 18
            [sex] => m
        )

)
*/

?>
```

Another variant sorting by value:

```
<?php 
$data = array(
"US" => "United States", 
"IN" => "India", 
"DE" => "Germany", 
"ES" => "Spain"
);

asort($data); 
print_r($data);
/*
Array ([DE] => Germany

[IN] => India

[ES] => Spain

[US] => United States

) 
*/
```

?>

My example array for sorting:

```
<?php
Array
(
    [0] => дувоздаҳҳазорсоларо
    [2] => мусовиулқувваро
    [3] => фарҳангшиносону
    [6] => илоҳиётшиносони
    [7] => сарнавиштпазирӣ
    [14] => сангнабиштаҳое
    [15] => илоҳиётшиносон
    [16] => музаффариятҳои
    [18] => минтақатулбурҷ
    [20] => фарҳангномаҳои
    [21] => парастишгоҳҳое
    [22] => кишваркушоиҳои
    [23] => парастишгоҳҳои
    [24] => фарҳангшиносон
    [26] => таҷъирнопазир
    [29] => илҳодшиносони
    [30] => сангнабиштаҳо
    [31] => сангнабиштҳои
    [32] => гумроҳкунанда
    [34] => байнаннаҳрайн
    [35] => наанҷомидааст
    [38] => парҳезкоронаи
    [39] => меҳрпарастист
    [42] => дареҷухвазата
    [45] => лашкаркашиҳои
    [47] => мовароуттабиӣ
    [49] => дастнахӯрдагӣ
    [51] => шаҳватпарастӣ
    [53] => аввалиндараҷа
    [56] => меҳрпарастиву
    [57] => ҷаҳоншиносиро
    [58] => меҳрпарастиро
    [60] => зарвонпарастӣ
    [62] => ҳастишиносиву
    [63] => муҳоҷираташон
    [65] => пажӯҳандагон
    [66] => бавуҷудомада
    [67] => ситорашиносӣ
    [72] => нӯҳҳазорсола
    [74] => аҳуромаздост
    [75] => ҷаҳонишиносӣ
);
?>
```

This result not sorting by my aplphabet from array:

```
<?php
    $array = array (
        "ӯктамҷон",
        "ғайрат",
        "маъруфҷон",
        "рустам",
        "карим",
        "ҳурматой",
        "тоҷикӣ",
        "забони тоҷикӣ",
        "адолат"
    );


    echo "<pre>";
        print_r($array);
    echo "</pre>";

    /*
    Array
    (
        [0] => ӯктамҷон
        [1] => ғайрат
        [2] => маъруфҷон
        [3] => рустам
        [4] => карим
        [5] => ҳурматой
        [6] => тоҷикӣ
        [7] => забони тоҷикӣ
        [8] => адолат
    )
    */

    setlocale(LC_ALL, "tg-Cyrl-TJ"); 
    sort($array, SORT_LOCALE_STRING);

    echo "<pre>";
        print_r($array);
    echo "</pre>";

    /*
    Array
    (
        [0] => адолат
        [1] => забони тоҷикӣ
        [2] => карим
        [3] => маъруфҷон
        [4] => тоҷикӣ
        [5] => рустам
        [6] => ғайрат
        [7] => ҳурматой
        [8] => ӯктамҷон
    )
    */

    /*  Result must be:
    Array
    (
        [0] => адолат
        [1] => ғайрат
        [2] => забони тоҷикӣ
        [3] => карим
        [4] => маъруфҷон
        [5] => рустам
        [6] => тоҷикӣ
        [7] => ӯктамҷон
        [8] => ҳурматой
    )
    */
?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use this function for sorting array values by any character order, which you need to provide as the second argument:

```
function customSort(&$arr, $charOrder) {
    $mappedChar = $charOrder;
    sort($mappedChar);
    $mapping = array_combine($charOrder, $mappedChar);
    foreach($arr as $str) {
        $mapped[] = strtr($str, $mapping);
    }
    return array_multisort($mapped, $arr);
}
```

Just like the standard PHP functions, it sorts the array *in-place*.

Here is how you would use it:

```
$charOrder = [
"а","б", "в", "г", "ғ", "д", "е", "ё", "ҷ", "ж", "з", "и", "ӣ", "й", "к", "қ", "л", "м", "н", "о", "п", "р", "с", "т", "у", "ӯ", "ф", "х", "ҳ", "ч", "ш", "ъ", "э", "ю", "я"
];

// Sample unsorted array
$arr = [
        "ӯктамҷон",
        "ғайрат",
        "маъруфҷон",
        "рустам",
        "карим",
        "ҳурматой",
        "тоҷикӣ",
        "забони тоҷикӣ",
        "адолат"
    ];

customSort($arr, $charOrder);
```

After running the above example, `$arr` will have this content:

```
array (
  'адолат',
  'ғайрат',
  'забони тоҷикӣ',
  'карим',
  'маъруфҷон',
  'рустам',
  'тоҷикӣ',
  'ӯктамҷон',
  'ҳурматой',
)
```

Comment: You function return "1" when I use it @trincot. Have you checked the function for performance? If so then give me a link so that I can look at it.

Comment: The function returns `true`, just like the standard `sort` function. The array passed as argument is *mutated* by the function, and will come out sorted. This is standard behaviour of sort functions in PHP. The performance should be fine, but cannot beat the built-in locale-based sorting methods in PHP. Does the function take too long for you?

Comment: I've array with 9000000 values and function is slightly delayed and this function can be a little faster?

Comment: I don't think there is much you can do to speed this up (except for using a suitable locale). The bottleneck is `strtr`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [sort function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sort.php) with the second parameter as you want the string to be sorted not in english. An example could be

```
setlocale("LC_ALL", "fr_FR.utf8"); 
sort($arraytobesorted, SORT_LOCALE_STRING);
```

Here you can change as per your language, I have used french as an example.

Comment: I changed my question and tested you answer but the result is not what I want @Rohit Ailani

Comment: It will be better for me if the sorting is on the specified letters in the array. There will be no problem even then when the language alphabet is exposed or reduced.