# How to quickly and optimally pull out of the text all the words with the letter "ӣ" in the array?

Tags: php, arrays, string, performance, explode

I've simple text and I want get all words with letter "ӣ" from text to array value. Example my text:

```
$text = "тоҷикӣ  барои забони тоҷикӣ ва барои давлати мо ҳамчун забони давлатӣ ба ҳисоб меравад. Дар давлати мо забонҳои ҳориҷӣ ба монанди забони русӣ, англисӣ, ӯзбекӣ ва арабӣ омӯзонида мешаванд.";
```

If the text found words with the letter "ӣ" then take that word and another word on the right of the same word and add it to the array. Another take that word and another word on the left and add it to the array.
**Here is roughly the result that should be:**

```
$result = array(
"тоҷикӣ  барои",
"забони тоҷикӣ",
"тоҷикӣ ва",
"забони давлатӣ",
"давлатӣ ба",
"забонҳои ҳориҷӣ",
"ҳориҷӣ ба",
"забони русӣ",
"русӣ, англисӣ",
"англисӣ, ӯзбекӣ",
"ӯзбекӣ ва",
"ва арабӣ",
"арабӣ омӯзонида"
);
```

My code to explode two words. I could only just split a line of two words:

```
$text = "тоҷикӣ  барои забони тоҷикӣ ва барои давлати мо ҳамчун забони давлатӣ ба ҳисоб меравад. Дар давлати мо забонҳои ҳориҷӣ ба монанди забони русӣ, англисӣ, ӯзбекӣ ва арабӣ омӯзонида мешаванд.";
    $array = array();

    preg_match_all('/([А-Яа-я0-9ҚӢҒҶҲӮқӣғҷҳӯ\.]+(?: [А-Яа-я0-9ҚӢҒҶҲӮқӣғҷҳӯ\.]+)?)/u',$text,$array);
    echo"<pre>";
    print_r($array);
    echo"<pre>";
    echo "<hr>";
    function array_flatten($array) { 
      if (!is_array($array)) { 
        return FALSE; 
      } 
      $result = array(); 
      foreach ($array as $key => $value) { 
        if (is_array($value)) { 
          $result = array_merge($result, array_flatten($value)); 
        } 
        else { 
          $result[$key] = $value; 
        } 
      } 
      return $result; 
    }

    $array = array_flatten($array);

    $array = array_filter(array_unique($array));



    foreach ($array as $key => $value) 
    {
         if (stripos($value, " ") === false) 
         {
            unset($array[$key]);
         }
    }



    echo"<pre>";
    print_r($array);
    echo"<pre>";

    /* Output
    Array
    (
        [1] => барои забони
        [2] => тоҷикӣ ва
        [3] => барои давлати
        [4] => мо ҳамчун
        [5] => забони давлатӣ
        [6] => ба ҳисоб
        [7] => меравад. Дар
        [8] => давлати мо
        [9] => забонҳои ҳориҷӣ
        [10] => ба монанди
        [11] => забони русӣ
        [13] => ӯзбекӣ ва
        [14] => арабӣ омӯзонида
    )
    */
```

Comment: I change my question. You can see it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would first split the words, and then use `array_reduce` to check every pair of words to see if either of them contains the target letter, and if so, include that pair in the output:

```
$result = [];
array_reduce(preg_split("~\s+~", $text), function($prev, $word) use (&$result) {
    if ($prev && (strpos($prev, "ӣ") !== false || strpos($word, "ӣ") !== false)) {
        $result[] = "$prev $word";
    }
    return $word;
});
```

For your `$text` value, `$result` would be:

```
array (
  'тоҷикӣ барои',
  'забони тоҷикӣ',
  'тоҷикӣ ва',
  'забони давлатӣ',
  'давлатӣ ба',
  'забонҳои ҳориҷӣ',
  'ҳориҷӣ ба',
  'забони русӣ,',
  'русӣ, англисӣ,',
  'англисӣ, ӯзбекӣ',
  'ӯзбекӣ ва',
  'ва арабӣ',
  'арабӣ омӯзонида',
)
```

Comment: How then do you make an associative array from this text replacing some letters in words and these words passing as the key and the original words into the value of the array? This example variables to replace letters:                                                                              
$search  = array("ғ","ӣ","ҷ","ҳ","қ","ӯ","Ғ","Ӣ","Ҷ","Ҳ","Қ","Ӯ");
$replace = array("г","и","ч","х","к","у","Г","И","Ч","Х","К","У");

Comment: Example: $array = array("точики барои"=>"тоҷикӣ барои");

Comment: That sounds like a different question... But look into using `$result2[str_replace( 
             array("ғ","ӣ","ҷ","ҳ","қ","ӯ","Ғ","Ӣ","Ҷ","Ҳ","Қ","Ӯ"),
             array("г","и","ч","х","к","у","Г","И","Ч","Х","К","У"),
             $pair)] = $pair;`

Comment: Thanks, working all @trincot. Sorry but would like to ask if you can answer this [question] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46537875/how-to-sort-a-large-array-according-to-the-alphabet-specified-in-the-array-with)